# How to handle "whens" while using dynamic hostnames in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am generating a dynamic EC2 inventory in Ansible and executing a playbook against it. In this case, I have a role that runs against three servers in that inventory. However, some of the actions are only run on the first machine, then the other servers are able to use files created by the first one.

Before switching to the dynamic inventory, I was able to modify what ran on each host based on the hostname as it rolled through each of the machines. i.e.

```yaml
Create new file01
when: inventory_hostname == "host-01"
```

```yaml
Copy new file01
when: inventory_hostname != "host-01"
```

Is there a good way to do this with a dynamic inventory? Right now all three of those machines are in a single keyed group, but the hostname could be anything. Also, it's not important that the first host is the one that generates the file. It could be any of the three.

Comment: If you are targeting those three hosts in the `hosts` of the playbook, then limit the taks via `run_once: true`. Otherwise delegate the taks to the first host of the group `delegate_to: "{{ groups.group_name.0 }}"` and add a `run_once: true`, once again. All of those techniques being explained in the documentation: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_delegation.html

Comment: Thank you. {{ groups.group_name.0 }} was exactly what I needed.